# Как проверить тип Character на равенство с определенными символами?

Tags: java, if, char, сравнение, символы

У меня есть `Character character = '!'`. Как я могу его проверить на то, что является ли он одним из этих символов или нет: `'!', '?', '.', ',', ':'`.

Если более подробно, то делаю проверку символа в операторе `if`, и если он не равен этим символам, добавляю в `StringBuilder`.

```java
 for (Character ch : inputChars) {
     if (ch != '.' || ch != ',' || ch != '?') {
         stringBuilder.append(ch);
     }
 }
```

Хочется сделать что-то типо этого:

```java
if (ch.equals("[^a-zA-Z-^а-яА-Я]+"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поработать на прямую с классом `String`:

```java
   char inputChar = '.'; // for example
   String charToString = String.valueOf(inputChar);
      if (charToString.matches("[!.;:\\-'\\s]+")) {
          // your action ...
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать коллекцию с символами и проверять входит ли наш символ в коллекцию:

```
Set<Character> allowedChar = "!?.,:".chars()
       .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());

if (allowedChars.contains(ch)) {
  ...
}
```